# c++ bad class instance

Tags: c++, class

I have this code and the exercise is to find out which error will occur if I build an Instance of my Class and delete it afterwards. I can't find the fault in the definition of this class so maybe you can help me. Here's the code:

```
class BadClass{
public:
BadClass(){
    p = new double;
}
~BadClass () {}

    double getValue() {return *p;}
    void setValue(double v) {*p = v;}

private:
    double* p;
};
```

Comment: See [Rule_of_three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)

Answer (score 2):

You call `new double` in the constructor without a corresponding `delete p` call in the destructor.

This will result in a memory leak.

Comment: Alright thank you @APerson I already thought about this so the standard destructor does not delete dynamic allocated memory?

Comment: @Franklinprogs no, you must manage the memory ownership manually in C++. You can however use `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>` helper classes

Comment: @Erbureth: or even `double` in this case.